# Save attached files from list box in Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010, filepath

I have a form that allows the user to add files and a list box that lists these added files:

```
Private Sub cmdFileDialog_Click()
' Add Files button
' Using this to open the File Dialog box and save attachment file location paths

   Dim fDialog As Office.FileDialog
   Dim varFile As Variant
   Dim varFileName As String

' Set up the File dialog box.
   Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
   With fDialog
  ' Allow the user to make multiple selections in the dialog box.
      .AllowMultiSelect = True

  ' Set the title of the dialog box.
      .Title = "Select One or More Files"

  ' Show the dialog box. If the .Show method returns True, the
  ' user picked at least one file. If the .Show method returns
  ' False, the user clicked Cancel.
      If .Show = True Then
     ' This loops through each file that is selected and then add it to the list box.
        'For Each varFile In .SelectedItems
        '   Me.FileList.AddItem varFile
        'Next

     ' This loops through each file that is selected and adds the entire file's path to the invisible list.
     ' Will use this invisible list to save locations of any attachments to this record in the ideaAttachmentPath field in tblIdeaDetails
        For Each varFile In .SelectedItems
           Me.InvisiblePathList.AddItem varFile
        Next

  ' This goes through each selected file and extracts just file's name rather than full path name (accomplished above)
  ' and adds file names to list box
     For Each varFile In .SelectedItems
         varFileName = Dir(varFile)
         Me.FileList.AddItem varFileName
         attachmentsAdded = True
     Next

     Me.ClearListBoxButton.Visible = True
     Me.AttachedLabel.Visible = True
     Me.FileList.Visible = True
  End If
End With

End Sub
```

What I'm hoping to accomplish is saving these added files onto a network folder after the user has clicked a button (specifically, a Save button). How can I go about looping through the list box of files and copying these files into a network folder? Here's what I have so far:

```
Function SaveAttachments()
    Dim fileName As Variant
    Dim fileDestination As String
    Dim attachment As Integer

    For attachment = 0 To Me.FileList.ListCount
        'MsgBox (FileList.ItemData(x))
        FileList.ItemData(attachment).Text = fileName
        'build the destination
        fileDestination = "path here"
        'copy the file to the new folder
        FileCopy fileName, fileDestination
    Next

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
Sub SaveAttachments()

    Dim fileDestination As String
    Dim i As Long

    'Update this to the correct folder, be sure to include the ending \
    fileDestination = "Drive:\Path\To\Folder\"

    For i = 0 To Me.FileList.ListCount - 1
        FileCopy Me.InvisiblePathList.ItemData(i) & Application.PathSeparator & Me.FileList.ItemData(i), fileDestination & Me.FileList.ItemData(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I probably should've mentioned that I'm working with Access 2010. 

I had to change Me.FileList.Count to Me.FileList.ListCount because Access was giving me an error. It's now giving me an error on Me.InvisiblePathList.List(i). What's the purpose of the .List(i)?

Comment: Nevermind, I believe I've figured it out. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction @tigeravatar. Here's what I've modified it to be:

Comment: 'Update this to the correct folder, be sure to include the ending \
    fileDestination = "myPathHere"

    For i = 0 To Me.FileList.ListCount - 1
        FileCopy Me.InvisiblePathList.ItemData(i) & "\" & Me.FileList.ItemData(i), fileDestination & Me.FileList.ItemData(i)
    Next i

Comment: I'm glad you got it working!  I have edited the answer to reflect your solution :)